# Data on Palestinian and Israeli casualties by years

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, palestine, statistics, data-sources

I am looking for data on Palestinian and Israeli casualties in the past - from 1948 (creation of Israel) or earlier to our days, preferably in a downloadable form.

One of the questions that I find potentially interesting is whether there is a significant increase in deaths associated with certain milestones - like Hamas's creation (1987) and adoption of its [1988 charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Hamas_charter), the beginning of the [peace process (1993)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Accords), and the rise of Netanyahu (2009).

I have found so far only the data in form of figures:
[from 2000 to 2017](https://www.vox.com/2014/7/14/5898581/chart-israel-palestine-conflict-deaths)
[image]

[from 1987 to 2021](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2021/05/18/the-israel-palestine-conflict-has-claimed-14000-lives-since-1987)
[image]

It is possible that before a certain point, Palestinians were not acknowledged as a separate nation, but rather lumped together with Jordanians, Egyptians, and other hosting nations. If a definite statement can be made to this extent, it is also of interest.

Comment: See [Demographic history of Palestine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographic_history_of_Palestine_(region)#Early_Ottoman_period)

Comment: One mistake I made was thinking that death data could be retrieved from the population. But this is wrong. Palestinians migrated to other countries and Jews migrated to Israel from other countries. So the data is hard to analyze, at least for me.

Comment: @C.F.G there are also natural deaths. Besides, both populations have grown significantly due to high birth rates (especially in Gaza, something like 7 kids per woman, higher than anywhere in the Arab world.)

Comment: Are you asking about death from all causes as the title of your Q might suggest, or just "conflict deaths" given your source/graph?

Comment: @Fizz I am interested in casualties, like in the graphs shown.